# Alternative for malloc_trim(0)

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I am allocating memory using Malloc .after the usage I am using delete to free the memory.To release this memory to OS I am using malloc_trim(0). but Malloc_trim (0) is deprecated.So I would like to know   if there is any other alternative for malloc_trim(0). By the way the language is cpp

Comment: _I am allocating memory using Malloc .after the usage I am using delete to free the memory._ FYI: Memory allocated by `malloc()` or `calloc()` must be released by `free()`. Memory allocated by `new` must be released by `delete` (`new[]` by `delete[]` resp.) Mixing `malloc()` and `delete` is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) (even if it seems to work).

Comment: _"I am allocating memory using Malloc .after the usage I am using delete to free the memory."_ - I hope you use `free()`, not `delete`. Why do you even use those functions in C++? I guess the alternative is to _not_ use the memory management functions from C at all, or, in modern C++, avoid manual memory management at all where possible.

Comment: Is it really deprecated? Where did you read that?

Answer (score 0):

i believe that you can use `free()` key word instead of `malloc_trim(0)`. i think that using `malloc()` is pretty old as modernly it uses `new` as a substitute. if you are using `new` keyword, you can use `delete` keyword to release the memory from the heap.

Comment: No, `free()` is something else. See the [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_trim.3.html).

Comment: `new` and `delete` are completely different to `malloc()` and `free()`. The former is not just a substitute to the latter. You might have reasons to use `malloc()` instead of `new`.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the `malloc/delete` confusion, the alternative to calling `malloc_trim` is simply **not** calling `malloc_trim`. It's deprecated because it's pointless nowadays.

Comment: Why is it pointless nowadays?

Comment: @Zacryon: Because the OS can reclaim physical RAM without it, and you don't need to return address space. Address space is now virtual, you get your 4 GB even on small embedded systems. On 64 bits systems address space is pretty impossible to exhaust.